# How do you make python create lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i dident know really how to write the title but i hope i can explain it better.
Anyway im making a tool for Cable marking for my work. Its pretty simple the program asks what the Cable name is and how many parts it has. then it should print it out. This is how i want it to work. The program will ask the Cable name lets say Cableone and then it asks how many parts lets say 3 then it should print
cableone.1
cableone.2
cableone.3
Now my problem is the last part where it should make the list i dont know how to write it. Could any one help me with it? This is my code so far.

```
cabelname = input("Whats the cable name?:")
parts = input("How many parts do your cable have?:")

print(cabelname + "." + parts)
```

Comment: You should read some manuals, tutorials and books about python. There are plenty of resources online that can help you, even interactive ones like [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python).

Comment: for i in range(int(parts)): print(cablename+"."+i)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find more how to build a lists in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Longer version:

```
cablename = input("What's the cable name?: ")
parts = input("How many parts do your cable have?: ")
cables = []

for i in range(1, int(parts) + 1):
    cable = cablename + "." + str(i)
    cables.append(cable)
    print(cable)
```

Shorter version:

```
cablename = input("What's the cable name?: ")
parts = input("How many parts do your cable have?: ")

cables = [cablename + "." + str(i) for i in range(1, int(parts) + 1)]
print(" ".join(cables))
```

If you want to have each part in different line, change last line to:

```
print("\n".join(cables))
```